# Possible to use more than one core with sed and bash?

Tags: bash, sed, bash-scripting

I am looking to use more than one core when replacing values with sed in bash, is this possible?

Comment: How complex is the sed script that multiple cores would be any sort of help?

Comment: You could just split the file and process each half in a different sed process, but if the script is complicated and involves tweaking the different sed spaces, it wouldn’t work. On simple scripts it should work, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer: probably no.

Longer answer: It really depends. What's your sed like? What's the input/output? Is it multiple scripts and multiple input files? Then you can run multiple instances, and the scheduler will probably distribute this to run on multiple cores. Is it one long input file? then the answer is maybe, but probably not.

Maybe you can split the file into chunks and process those ONLY under certain strict conditions, namely your sed doesn't care about line numbers. Something like "delete line 2" is very different on a single file vs one file chunked to pieces. sed can use state, and if you split the file, you'd have to keep this editing state consistent.

Answer (score 1):

You might try running several scripts in parallel. See this question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79501/executing-piped-commands-in-parallel

As you will see in my own answer, it's not automatic that multiple cores will allow you to get faster results (though of course it *can* happen).

Answer (score 0):

Usually, that cannot be done with SED. If you are wanting better performance, perhaps you could try using AWK or Python3 instead.